# Need Label to Show every time Condition is true

Tags: pine-script

I did a simple MACD Indicator where it puts a label when the MACD Hist Line crosses above or below 0. The problem is it only puts the label the 2 most recent times it happens (one for the short and one for the long)... and not every time it also previously happen. i.e. I have a symbol on the chart... I put the indicator on... it will show the label of the most recent "Sell Now" label (when the most recent sell condition occurred) and the "Buy Now" label when the most recent buy condition occurred... but it won't show labels for all of the previous times the buy or sell conditions were true. I attached the image so you can see. As you can see in the image... it only shows a label for the most recent conditions being true... but as you can see, the histLine (the colored bars) crossed above and below the 0 line a bunch of times but not labels were shown for those. If you can give me some guidance on how I can fix that - would appreciate it. Other indicators will show every time it occurred… current, recently and in the past – all across the time scale… that is what I would like to do.

Here is the code:

```
//@version=4
study("mwgMACD")
src = input(title="Source", type=input.source, defval=ohlc4) [macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = macd(src, 12, 26, 5)

col_grow_above = #26A69A
col_grow_below = #FFCDD2
col_fall_above = #B2DFDB
col_fall_below = #EF5350
col_macd = #0094ff
col_signal = #ff6a00

//plot(macdLine, color=color.green)
//plot(signalLine, color=color.red)
//plot(histLine, color=color.white, style=plot.style_histogram)

plot(histLine, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(histLine>=0 ? (histLine[1] < histLine ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (histLine[1] < histLine ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below) ), transp=0 )

ShowCross = input(title="Show Cross", type=input.bool, defval=true)

conditionBuy1 = histLine[1] < 0 and histLine > 0
//conditionBuy2 = histLine crossed over 0

conditionSell2 = histLine[1] > 0 and histLine < 0

if ShowCross and crossover(histLine, 0)
    var label1 = label.new(bar_index, na, text="BUY NOW")
    label.set_x(label1, 0)
    label.set_xloc(label1, time, xloc.bar_time)
    label.set_color(label1, color.green)
    label.set_size(label1, size.small)
    label.set_textcolor(label1,color.white)

if ShowCross and crossunder(histLine, 0)
    var label2 = label.new(bar_index, na, text="SELL NOW")
    label.set_x(label2, 0)
    label.set_xloc(label2, time, xloc.bar_time)
    label.set_color(label2, color.red)
    label.set_size(label2, size.small)
    label.set_textcolor(label2,color.white)
```

Here is an image so you can see what I'm talking about:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx224.png

Answer (score 0):

Mike G.

The below is slightly different code but I believe it achieves your aim

```
//@version=4
study("StackOverFlow")
src = input(title="Source", type=input.source, defval=ohlc4) 

[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = macd(src, 12, 26, 5)

col_grow_above = #26A69A
col_grow_below = #FFCDD2
col_fall_above = #B2DFDB
col_fall_below = #EF5350
col_macd = #0094ff
col_signal = #ff6a00


plot(histLine, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(histLine>=0 ? (histLine[1] < histLine ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (histLine[1] < histLine ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below) ), transp=0 )

ShowCross = input(title="Show Cross", type=input.bool, defval=true)

conditionBuy1 = histLine[1] < 0 and histLine > 0
conditionSell2 = histLine[1] > 0 and histLine < 0


Buy = crossover(histLine, 0)
plotshape(ShowCross and Buy, location=location.top, style=shape.labeldown, color=color.green, size=size.tiny, text="Buy", textcolor=color.white, transp=0, offset=0)

Sell = crossunder(histLine, 0)
plotshape(ShowCross and Sell,  location=location.bottom, style=shape.labelup, color=color.red, size=size.tiny, text="Sell", textcolor=color.white, transp=0, offset=0)
```

Example Link that might assist
https://uk.tradingview.com/script/elLlG7Rj-blackcat-L1-MACD-with-Overbought-and-Oversold-Detection/

Comment: WOW - it works... thanks for the quick help.

How do I make it so it's like the labels I had - ie. Says Buy or Sell and what in my code was preventing it from doing what I needed it to do... ie. put the buy or sell signal more than just the most recent occurent?

Comment: Anyone know how to do this with Labels rather than plotshapes? The code he provided did have the signals show up across the entire timeframe like I needed... BUT it's not done with labels... I was hoping to get it done with labels like how my example image showed (although my image only produces the most recent occurrence of the buy and sell for some reason... rather than every time the condition was true). I'm trying to have it show every occurrence the condition was true... but using the labels to show the buy or sell signal.

Comment: Mike G, I personally haven't enough knowledge on labels as per your script but I have updated my answer above to use the label setting within plotshape style=shape.labelup/down. Hope it helps.

Comment: Added a link within my answer to a script that might assist.

Answer (score 0):

The operator `var` creates one global variable, and you need your own variable for each label. Here is a script that you would like.

```
//@version=4
study("Help (mwgMACD)")
src = input(title="Source", type=input.source, defval=ohlc4) 

[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = macd(src, 12, 26, 5)

col_grow_above = #26A69A
col_grow_below = #FFCDD2
col_fall_above = #B2DFDB
col_fall_below = #EF5350
col_macd = #0094ff
col_signal = #ff6a00

//plot(macdLine, color=color.green)
//plot(signalLine, color=color.red)
//plot(histLine, color=color.white, style=plot.style_histogram)

plot(histLine, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(histLine>=0 ? (histLine[1] < histLine ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (histLine[1] < histLine ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below) ), transp=0 )

ShowCross = input(title="Show Cross", type=input.bool, defval=true)

conditionBuy1 = histLine[1] < 0 and histLine > 0
//conditionBuy2 = histLine crossed over 0

conditionSell2 = histLine[1] > 0 and histLine < 0

if ShowCross and crossover(histLine, 0)
    label.new(bar_index, 0, text="BUY NOW", textcolor=color.white, size=size.small, color=color.green)
    // label.set_x(label1, 0)
    // label.set_xloc(label1, time, xloc.bar_time)
    // label.set_color(label1, color.green)
    // label.set_size(label1, size.small)
    // label.set_textcolor(label1,color.white)

if ShowCross and crossunder(histLine, 0)
    label.new(bar_index, 0, text="SELL NOW", textcolor=color.white, size=size.small, color=color.red)
//     label.set_x(label2, 0)
//     label.set_xloc(label2, time, xloc.bar_time)
//     label.set_color(label2, color.red)
//     label.set_size(label2, size.small)
//     label.set_textcolor(label2,color.white)
```

Comment: If the answer is complete for you, use the recommendations of the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).